# Error: Conversion from type DBNull to type string is not valid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2003

again i came for a problem. Please help me to do this. I was tried to get quantity from db make use of the selection in list box. I got answered with listbox1. If i selected the item in listbox1 the quantity would appear in textbox1. But in this same code will not work for listbox2 with textbox4.. Here i given the code...

```
 $Con.open()
 $Dim cd as new oledb.oledbcommand("Select Quantity from tlist where tool_name"& "'"listbox2.selecteditem & "'" & "", con)
 $dim rs as oledb.oledbdatareader
 $do while rs.read
 $textbox4.text=(rs("Quantity))
 $loop
 $con.close
```

Here i got the error as "Conversion from type DBNull to type string is not valid" Plz let me know what will i do.??

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues.

1. Your query is a bit off. It currently reads **Select Quantity from tlist where tool_name'valueOfListbox2'"**. It should probably read **Select Quantity from tlist where tool_name = 'valueOfListbox2'**.
2. Your getting a null value back and are not checking for a null return before writing the value out, hence the error. You can use the following IF statement to verify your value is not null:

   If NOT IsDbNull(rs("Quantity")) Then
3. Also, you're missing a double quote around "Quantity".